# Загрузка gPXE по сети

Tags: linux

Привет всем. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать загрузку `gPXE` минуя загрузку файлов через `tftp`?

Comment: опиши **подробно**, что ты хочешь сделать (**очень** подробно)

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно [по HTTP](http://etherboot.org/wiki/httpboot), [или iSCSI или AoE](http://etherboot.org/wiki/sanboot).

Но вопрос какой-то странный, так что поддерживаю предложение подробно описать что именно хочется получить.